# How to use UserDetailsService after upgrade Spring Boot 2.7.x to Spring Boot 3.0.0?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Spring Boot 2.7

File `UserDetailsImpl.java`

```java
package com.example.security.services;

import com.example.models.User;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String email;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public UserDetailsImpl(Long id, String username, String email, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    public static UserDetailsImpl build(User user) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles().stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName().name())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new UserDetailsImpl(user.getId(), user.getUsername(), user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;
        UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, user.id);
    }

}
```

File `UserDetailsServiceImpl.java`

```java
package com.example.security.services;

import com.example.models.User;
import com.example.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found with username: " + username));
        return UserDetailsImpl.build(user);
    }

}
```

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity extends ... (
        // securedEnabled = true,
        // jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
```

I tried in Spring Boot 3.0.0

```java
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) {
        // UserDetails user = User.builder().username("user").password("{noop}test").authorities("user").build();
        return userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
```

[image]

[image]

But syntax error, how to re-write correctly?

Comment: It already is an `@Service` and thus detected. You don't need anything else.

Comment: Seemly I need customize by password_encoder, password_decoder, not default AuthenticationManagerBuilder... I am not sure, I am have very little knowledge in Spring Security. Please write for me specific lines of code.

Comment: You don't need to. Expose the `PasswordEncoder` as a bean. That is all with the newer versions of Spring Security. I strongly suggest a read of the upgrade documentation.